# Capistrano deployment without git command on shared host?

Tags: git, zend-framework, capistrano, shared-hosting

- Developer A - Local Repository --> pulls/push ---> github
- Developer B - Local Repository --> pulls/push ---> github
- Capistrano would remain on our developers' machines, however we will define :repository to point to our GitHub project: set :repository, "git@github.com:myuser/myproject.git" # My clone url
- Developer A OR Developer B must be allowed to deploy committed files to the production machine.

I'm not sure about the third point here, is this possible?

I've been told by ctcherry here [On this workflow, does git command needs to be installed on the production server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319198/on-this-workflow-does-git-command-needs-to-be-installed-on-the-production-server) that:

> 1) By default Capistrano will deploy
>   from the repository, so the files
>   getting deployed would come from the
>   code that is checked into github. You
>   can configure Capistrano to deploy it
>   from the developers local machine by
>   using a different "deployment
>   strategy" See here:
>   http://rubydoc.info/gems/capistrano/2.5.19/Capistrano/Deploy/Strategy/Copy

But I still have doubts here.

If we use this approach, what would the **exact** work-flow be here?

- From developer machine A - We grab the committed files from github using Capistrano.
- From that same developer machine A - We deploy those files into the shared host via SSH and the files will be placed on their correct places?

Is that it?

**Update:**
Please I've never used either Git or Capistrano Deploy however, I'm doing my best to try to understand how all this may work, in order to allow a good workflow development process for my ZF based applications.

So my questions are really basic ones.

If I must provide any additional information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tim got it right down below, with the zip/unzip. Sorry I didn't see your message on the other post earlier.

Comment: @ctcherry - Oh please. Worry not. You have been 5 starts on help me out. :) Thank you both! really. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow is the same. What happens is, whenever either developer tries to deploy the project, Capistrano will first checkout a fresh copy of the project into a temp directory on their machine, zip it up, and upload it to the remote server. On the remote server the archive will then be decompressed and everything else works as normal.

Note that this approach is considerably slower that a 'normal' deployment, especially if your Internet connection is slow, since the whole project is being copied up each time.

Comment: My internet connection is ok. The reasons for all those questions is just: Should I leave my shared host company that doesn't allow git command and addopt this way, or this could get messy, and I really should do this the "right way"? Let's say my shared host company allows me to install very specific git commands, (not git command itself), my question is: what specific git command or commands will capistrano use on this scenario? (IF THE ABOVE doesn't make any sense, please tell me so and why). Thanks a lot. And I'm really sorry to take your time once again... Regards.

Comment: If you host doesn't allow git to be installed this approach is absolutely fine. The time the deployment takes is the only downside really, so if this isn't an issue then just I'd stick with that.

Comment: @MEM its also possible to use a custom deployment strategy, for example using Rsync to make those deploys faster, here is one that someone made that does such a thing: https://github.com/vigetlabs/capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache/tree Note: I haven't tested it.